# EPIC FHIR API Token generation issue

Tags: oauth-2.0, epic, smart-on-fhir

Issue in getting an Access Token
I have received an error that "**Failed to retrieve Authorization code from Launch Token.**" in Postman.
Unable to receive the Access token using &iss and &launch.

We are following these steps:

1. Passing the Query Parameters-

- iss - https://fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-oauth/api/FHIR/STU3
- launch token -
- state - abc123
- code -
  After that getting an error "Failed to retrieve Authorization code from Launch Token."

Issue in getting an Access Token
I have received an error that "**Failed to retrieve Authorization code from Launch Token.**" in Postman.
Unable to receive the Access token using &iss and &launch.

We are following these steps:

1. Passing the Query Parameters-

- iss - https://fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-oauth/api/FHIR/STU3
- launch token -
- state - abc123
- code -
  After that getting an error "Failed to retrieve Authorization code from Launch Token."

We are expecting **Access Token**.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your shared workflow, you aren't even at the point of obtaining an access token. First you would exchange the launch code for an authorization code, which appears to be the step that's failing.

The first question to answer is how you expect your app to launch. Launch codes are only relevant for SMART on FHIR app launches. If your app is a SMART on FHIR app, you're better off testing the launch with the [LaunchPad](https://open.epic.com/Launchpad). You can't just make up any launch code in Postman and have it work.

If you are planning a different kind of launch, then you need to follow [the correct steps](https://fhir.epic.com/Documentation?docId=oauth2) for the launch type you expect to have. Neither standalone launches nor back-end integrations use launch codes.